# Tool for increasing .JS versions (*.js?v1, *.js?v2, ...) for preventing browser cache?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, version-control, auto-increment

I need to increase the javascript file versions in my project automatically, that my users always have the correct javascript code in their browsers and not the cache.

Each time I release a new version of my project, I need to change every .js file, that is included in a .aspx file.

**For example:**

SampleFile.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js" />
```

Starting a tool change ingreases the version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js?v1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js?v1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js?v1" />
```

Next version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js?v2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js?v2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js?v2" />
```

and so on...

I have many files, so it is frustrating to change every file each time.

Comment: define a constant or something and use that!

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js?v<%  response.write(VERSIONCONSTANT) %>" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than incrementing an integer, let your version flag be a hash of the content of the file. This way, your cache invalidation will be entirely automatic. Also, you would want to combine those files. [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/) handles both these issues for you (as well as minifying and GZipping).

Answer (score 0):

Most people run a build script when they release their project to QA/Production. The build script can handle adding the version numbers and do the file compressions. Look into [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)